WinHttpReadData is giving wrong characters
I am using WinHttpReadData to read response from server . I can read normal English text without any problem , but if it contains other language characters inside the English paragraph , it converts it into a weird characters .
For example the server is sending this ,A5E53513712A_RS-AA_001_1-Trichter Abstandsstück 30mm but I am receiving like this , A5E53513712A_RS-AA_001_1-Trichter AbstandsstÃ¼ck 30mm.
Here is my code ,
bool RealWinHttp::readData(HINTERNET iHRequest, LPSTR oLpBuffer, DWORD iDwNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD oLpdwNumberOfBytesRead)
{
    ZeroMemory(oLpBuffer, iDwNumberOfBytesToRead + 1);
    WinHttpReadData(iHRequest, (LPVOID)oLpBuffer, iDwNumberOfBytesToRead, oLpdwNumberOfBytesRead);
    
    return oLpdwNumberOfBytesRead;
}

std::string AMNRequest::readResponse(HINTERNET iHRequest, HANDLE downloadFileHandle)
{
    DWORD size = 0;
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    LPSTR buffer = nullptr;
    std::string response;
    do {
        size = 0;
        bytesRead = 0;      
        if (baseWinHttp->isQueryDataAvailable(iHRequest, &size) && size)
        {
                buffer = new char[size+1];
                if (baseWinHttp->readData(iHRequest, buffer, size, &bytesRead))
                {
                    if (downloadFileHandle)
                    {
                        DWORD bytesWritten;
                        WriteFile(downloadFileHandle, buffer, bytesRead, &bytesWritten, NULL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.append(buffer, bytesRead);
                        response.shrink_to_fit();
                    }
                }

                delete []buffer;
                buffer = nullptr;
        }       
    } while (size > 0);

    response.shrink_to_fit();

    return response;
}

finally I am reading response string .
I tried to convert buffer to utf-8 and utf-16 as well . still both are giving same result . Here is the code I am using (which I got from chat gpt) to convert utf-8 and utf-16.
std::wstring ConvertToUTF16(const char* input, size_t inputLength) {
    // Calculate the length of the buffer required for the UTF-16 string
    int utf16Length = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, inputLength, NULL, 0);
    if (utf16Length == 0) {
        // Error occurred, handle it accordingly
        return L"";
    }

    // Allocate memory for the UTF-16 string
    std::wstring utf16Buffer(utf16Length, L'\0');

    // Convert the input to UTF-16
    if (!::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, inputLength, &utf16Buffer[0], utf16Length)) {
        // Error occurred, handle it accordingly
        return L"";
    }

    return utf16Buffer;
}


std::string ConvertToUTF8(const char* input, size_t inputLength) {
    // Calculate the length of the buffer required for the UTF-8 string
    int utf8Length = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, inputLength, NULL, 0);
    if (utf8Length == 0) {
        // Error occurred, handle it accordingly
        return "";
    }

    // Allocate memory for the UTF-16 string
    std::wstring utf16Buffer(utf8Length, L'\0');

    // Convert the input to UTF-16
    if (!::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, inputLength, &utf16Buffer[0], utf8Length)) {
        // Error occurred, handle it accordingly
        return "";
    }

    // Calculate the length of the buffer required for the UTF-8 string
    int utf8BufferSize = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16Buffer.c_str(), utf16Buffer.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8BufferSize == 0) {
        // Error occurred, handle it accordingly
        return "";
    }

    // Allocate memory for the UTF-8 string
    std::string utf8Buffer(utf8BufferSize, '\0');

    // Convert the UTF-16 string to UTF-8
    if (!::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16Buffer.c_str(), utf16Buffer.length(), &utf8Buffer[0], utf8BufferSize, NULL, NULL)) {
        // Error occurred, handle it accordingly
        return "";
    }

    return utf8Buffer;
}

And I tried calling these functions like this ,
std::wstring test = ConvertToUTF16(buffer, bytesRead);
std::string testStr(test.begin(), test.end());
response.append(ConvertToUTF8( buffer, bytesRead));
response.shrink_to_fit();

the variables tesStr and response produce wring results only. I guess these two headers might be helpful ,
Content-Type : application/json
Transfer-Encoding : chunked

can anyone please help me . Thanks in advance .

Converting to UTF-8 is pointless, since the website is already giving you UTF-8. Instead, you need to convert from UTF-8 to your local codepage, or use something that can just output UTF-8.

The code is converting from CP_ACP (local codepage) to UTF-16. You need to convert from UTF-8 (CP_UTF8) instead. JSON is typically transmitted using UTF-8. Also, you can't convert your raw buffer as it might contain incomplete data between reads. Read everything as-is into your response first, then convert that to UTF-16 if needed only after all reading is done.

Side note: shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request. Because it has significant performance implications, getting and putting away memory is one of the most expensive things you can do, it is allowed to be totally ignored. And because it has significant performance implications if it actually does something, don't throw it around lightly. Finish building the string and then consider shrinking.

@RemyLebeau this doesn't help me . std::wstring test = ConvertToUTF16(response.data(), response.size()); . Also , if server is sending utf-8 , and buffer is char[]. How char[] can handle utf-8 ?

@sureshkumar it will work just fine if 1) response contains UTF-8 bytes, and 2) ConvertToUTF16() converts using CP_UTF8. Also, char handles UTF-8 just fine, but if you are really worried about it then simply use std::vector<unsigned char> (or char8_t) instead of std::string

@RemyLebeau if I check raw buffer after this line , WinHttpReadData(iHRequest, (LPVOID)oLpBuffer, iDwNumberOfBytesToRead, oLpdwNumberOfBytesRead);   oLpBiffer contains wrong character only. If char can handle utf-8 , then it should have correct character right ?. If I check the same api with postman, it gives correct response. It means the response from api is correct and im doing something wrong.

The bytes are fine, you are simply viewing them wrong. Unicode character ü in UTF-8 is bytes 0xC3 0xBC, and those bytes interpreted/viewed as Latin1 is characters Ã¼, just as you are seeing. So the bytes are fine, you are just misinterpreting them

@RemyLebeau I changed ConvertToUTF16( ) function to convert using CP_UTF8 instead of CP_ACP. I am getting result as expected . From here I am getting std::wstring , but my code requires std::string . I am converting wstring to string like this std::string str(wstring.begin(), wstring.end()). For the example I provided here, which contains German characters it is working fine . For other languages,for example Tamil (Language in India) I am getting correct std::wstring from ConvertToUTF16(). but getting std::string from it fails .

@RemyLebeau Even I tried these two methods , WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wStr, inputLength, &str[0], bufferSize, nullptr, nullptr); && WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wStr, inputLength, &str[0], bufferSize, nullptr, nullptr); these are also failing . How can we handle all the languages ?

@sureshkumar std::string str(wstring.begin(), wstring.end()) is definitely the wrong way to convert std::wstring to std::string. Use std::wstring_convert or WideCharToMultiByte() or equivalent. So you need to decide what character encoding you want the std::string to hold, and convert accordingly. It sounds like you want UTF-8, and if the server is already sending you UTF-8 to begin with, then there is no need to involve std::wstring at all. You need to go buffer -> wstring -> string only when you are converting between different encodings from buffer -> string.

@RemyLebeau yeah, the question is why buffer contains ANSI values while it's already capable to hold utf-8? You already mentioned i am just miss interpreting. How to interpret correctly? While debugging if I check buffer value i should see server value as it is , not ANSI converted string. Because I am using this response in other places, like CreateFile API in winhttp , display dialogue. Everywhere this ANSI string only visible, not the utf-8.

"why buffer contains ANSI value" - as already described, your buffer holds correct UTF-8 bytes (verify that by looking at the value of the raw bytes). If you view/interpret the bytes incorrectly, you can see ANSI equivalents of the same bytes. "While debugging if I check buffer value i should see server value as it is , not ANSI converted string" - a debugger has no idea a char string holds UTF-8 unless you explicitly tell it so, otherwise it will likely display it in your default locale instead. Refer to your debugger's documentation to see what display options it supports.
